# Touchpad right click broken Dell XPS 13 9343 libinput Debian Buster

Tags: debian, synaptic, libinput

Right click has stopped working on the touchpad of my Dell XPS 13 (2015) 9343 for a few weeks now on Debian Testing (Buster). As in Wayland the `libinput` configuration is done through the UI (in my case GNOME) according to [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput), `synaptics` seems to be deprecated, and all `xorg` conf files seem to be ignored, I am unable to find a solution to this problem.

The only way to right click is to double tap the toucpad, and actually right clicking does simply perform a left click. Additionally, the `$ libinput` command returns `Command not found`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem under Arch, in my case it was actually a setting being overwritten with the update of latest Gnome.

Using gnome-tweaks under Keyboard & Mouse section, Mouse Click Emulation was set to "Fingers". I turned it off and turned on the "Area" option, which uses the bottom right of the touchpad for a right click.

After this right click works as before.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it. I sincerely hope this feature will be added to the normal settings menu in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

This [fix](https://medium.com/@pck/ubuntu-18-04-fix-for-right-click-not-working-touchpad-issues-40037ff249e1) worked for me on Debian buster

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method areas
```